# Get action of form on change of select box using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms on web page. I want form action of which select box is changed. All the form are same except hidden fields. There are no class or id to form. Below is the code structure.

```js
function sortFunction(){
   var action = $(this).closest('form').attr('action');
   alert(action);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPESH" action="xyz">
   <select name="nShip" onchange="sortFunction()">
     <option value="Any">Select Ship:</option>
     <option value="Any">Any</option>
   </select>
</form>
<form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPESH" action="abc">
   <select name="nShip" onchange="sortFunction()">
      <option value="Any">Select Ship:</option>
      <option value="Any">Any</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any error returning in the console ?

Comment: No, there is no error. it prints undefined

Comment: Try passing `this` to the function. `onchange="sortFunction(this)"` and then change your function to: `function sortFunction(selectbox) { var action = $(selectbox)..... }`. In your function, `this` will not be the select box.

Comment: how is this a php question? I removed the tag for it. That makes your question unclear. You can add it back in when you've shown relevance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good practice to inline js code.  But, if you need to do it, it's useful to pass the following two parameters:

- this  --> current element
- event --> event object

Hence, change your code from:

```
<select name="nShip" onchange="sortFunction()">
```

to:

```
<select name="nShip" onchange="sortFunction(this, event)">
```

The snippet:

```js
function sortFunction(ele, evt){
  var action = $(element).closest('table').find('form').attr('action');
  console.log(action);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" width="100%">
    <table class="header" width="100%" id="AutoNumber2">
        <tbody><tr>

            <td width="100%" colspan="2">

                <div align="center">
                    <center>
                        <table width="99%" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="8" width="100%">
                                    <font size="4">Filter your Results</font> </td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPERG" action="/international/CruisesQuery_EA.asp"></form>
                                <input type="hidden" name="Client" value="airganesha">
                                <input type="hidden" name="CurrentPage" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="nAct" value="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="SORT_TYPE" value="Date Ascending">

                                <form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPELN" action="/international/CruisesQuery_EA.asp"></form>
                                <input type="hidden" name="Client" value="airganesha">
                                <input type="hidden" name="CurrentPage" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="LastPage" value="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="SORT_TYPE" value="Date Ascending">
                                <form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPESH" action="/international/CruisesQuery_EA.asp"></form>
                                <input type="hidden" name="Client" value="airganesha">
                                <input type="hidden" name="CurrentPage" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="LastPage" value="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="elDate" value="20180201">
                                <input type="hidden" name="lsDate" value="20180301">
                                <input type="hidden" name="erlDate" value="01/02/18">
                                <input type="hidden" name="lstDate" value="01/03/18">
                                <input type="hidden" name="line" value="Any">
                                <input type="hidden" name="linename" value="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="nOperator" value="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Area" value="Anywhere">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Howlong" value="Any">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Standard" value="Any">
                                <input type="hidden" name="QFly" value="Yes">
                                <input type="hidden" name="wheelchair" value="No">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Children" value="No Preference">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Size" value="Any">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Embark" value="Any">
                                <input type="hidden" name="nAct" value="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="SORT_TYPE" value="Date Ascending">


                                <td align="center" width="144">
                                    <div class="styled-select">
                                        <select name="nShip" onchange="sortFunction(this)">

                                            <option value="Any">Select Ship:</option>
                                            <option value="Any">Any</option>
                                            <option value="496">
                                                Adonia   </option>
                                            <option value="243">
                                                Adventure of the Seas   </option>
                                            <option value="474">
                                                Allure of the Seas   </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </center>
                    </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: please check this url. there is select ship drop down. your code shows undefined. http://cruiseveda.com/cruise/common-form.php?formAction=CruisesQuery_EA.asp&Client=airganesha&CurrentPage=1&LastPage=24&elDate=20180201&lsDate=20180301&erlDate=01%2F02%2F18&lstDate=01%2F03%2F18&line=Any&Area=Anywhere&Howlong=Any&Standard=Any&QFly=Yes&wheelchair=No&Children=No+Preference&Size=Any&Embark=Any&nAct=&SubmitType=Ship&SORT_TYPE=Date+Ascending

Comment: @Er.MukeshSharma In your code you need a different selector:  **var action = $(element).closest('table').find('form').attr('action');** The form is a child of table!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the context of `this` is `window` when running that event handler, not the `<select>` element.  Fortunately, since you're already using jQuery, you can simply use jQuery to attach your event handler.  Remove that function and remove the `onchange=` attributes from the markup and simply attach a handler like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('select').on('change', function () {
    var action = $(this).closest('form').attr('action');
    alert(action);
  });
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/w60tmwsh/)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the element as parameter:

```js
function sortFunction(element){
   var action = $(element).closest('form').attr('action');
   alert(action);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPESH" action="xyz">
   <select name="nShip" onchange="sortFunction(this)">
     <option value="Any">Select Ship:</option>
     <option value="Any">Any</option>
   </select>
</form>

<form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPESH" action="abc">
   <select name="nShip" onchange="sortFunction(this)">
      <option value="Any">Select Ship:</option>
      <option value="Any">Any</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Please check this url  http://cruiseveda.com/cruise/common-form.php?formAction=CruisesQuery_EA.asp&Client=airganesha&CurrentPage=1&LastPage=24&elDate=20180201&lsDate=20180301&erlDate=01%2F02%2F18&lstDate=01%2F03%2F18&line=Any&Area=Anywhere&Howlong=Any&Standard=Any&QFly=Yes&wheelchair=No&Children=No+Preference&Size=Any&Embark=Any&nAct=&SubmitType=Ship&SORT_TYPE=Date+Ascending

Comment: There is select ship select box.

Answer (score 2):

Since your calling a global function the this variable will reference to the window.... I would recommend to pass the default event variable in your html and retrieve it in your function in that way you can access to the element that is triggering the event.

```js
function sortFunction(e){
  
   var action = $(e.currentTarget).closest('form').attr('action');
   alert(action);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPESH" action="xyz">
   <select name="nShip" onchange="sortFunction(event)">
     <option value="Any">Select Ship:</option>
     <option value="Any">Any</option>
   </select>
</form>
<form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPESH" action="abc">
   <select name="nShip" onchange="sortFunction(event)">
      <option value="Any">Select Ship:</option>
      <option value="Any">Any</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery give you [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function for the task. You can get action attribute of form on change event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change', function () {
    var action = $(this).closest('form').attr('action');
    alert(action);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about pass the id for the form into the function:

```
<form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPESH" action="xyz" id="formOne">
   <select name="nShip" onchange="sortFunction('formOne')">
     <option value="Any">Select Ship:</option>
     <option value="Any">Any</option>
   </select>
</form>
<form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPESH" action="abc" id="formTwo">
   <select name="nShip" onchange="sortFunction('formTwo')">
      <option value="Any">Select Ship:</option>
      <option value="Any">Any</option>
   </select>
</form>
<script>
function sortFunction(formId){
   var action = $('#' + formId).closest('form').attr('action');
   alert(action);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change', function () {
    var action = $(this).closest('form').attr('action');
    alert(action);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPESH" action="xyz">
  <select name="nShip">
     <option value="Any">Select Ship:</option>
     <option value="Any">Any</option>
   </select>
</form>
<form method="GET" name="FORM_TYPESH" action="abc">
  <select name="nShip">
      <option value="Any">Select Ship:</option>
      <option value="Any">Any</option>
   </select>
</form>
```